# Screening Enzymes?

Tags: enzymes

I wish to obtain a list of all known enzymes and then get rid of the ones that use cofactors, the ones that use ATP, and a few others. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to filter the [UniProt](http://www.uniprot.org/) database for this. For example, [this search query](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=ec%3A*+NOT+cofactor%3A%28chebi%3A*%29+NOT+annotation%3A%28type%3A%22catalytic+activity%22+atp%29+AND+reviewed%3Ayes&sort=score):

`ec:* NOT cofactor:(chebi:*) NOT annotation:(type:"catalytic activity" atp) AND reviewed:yes`

...gives you all manually curated (`reviewed:yes`) enzymes (`ec:*`) that don't have a cofactor (`NOT cofactor:(chebi:*)`) and don't catalyze reactions with ATP (`NOT annotation:(type:"catalytic activity" atp)`).